# MySql: Order randomly when order is 0, but use numbers before

Tags: mysql

I have this table
[image]

And I wanna retrieve all data but in a certain order. I want it to be orderd by the field order, but with 0 meaning at random and AFTER the actual numbers in that field have been ordered.
So if I did this:

```
var sqlString = "SELECT * \
FROM 10561_13581_tblOffers \
WHERE isVisible = 1 \
LIMIT " + start + "," + count
```

I want the result to be either:

"bücher oder so" - order 1
"frau mit haar" - order 3
"stein" - order 0
"ordermy" - order 0

OR the last two reversed, as they are supposed to be randomly ordered

"bücher oder so" - order 1
"frau mit haar" - order 3
"ordermy" - order 0
"stein" - order 0

But in both cases, order 1 and 3 are in order.

How would I make my query to have the desired result?
(ofc, this can be done with a lot more order numbers and a lot more rows with a 0 for order)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean expression `order = 0` is evaluated as `1` for `true` or `0` for `false` and can be used in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 10561_13581_tblOffers 
WHERE isVisible = 1
ORDER BY `order` = 0, --this will send all 0s at the end of the resultset
         `order`
```

If you actually want all `0`s to be sorted randomly you can add `RAND()` function:

```
ORDER BY `order` = 0, 
         `order`,
         RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN order = 0 THEN 99999999
  ELSE order END
```

like that the 0's will come at the end in no particular order.